# Add Featured Image as background if class exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't have any code samples to offer as this is more of a 'proof of concept' kind of thing.

Is it possible in Wordpress / PHP when looping through posts to add a featured image as a background to a div PROVIDED a class exists on that div?

I cannot add the image directly in the template.

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't really enough to go off of here. You can't add the image in the template, but you have the ability to add PHP? WordPress is full of hooks and boolean functions that you can use. Parsing element classes and IDs with PHP is generally not recommended though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you can use for image background for the div

**Using inline style in the div itself**

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    /* grab the url for the full size featured image */
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); 

    /* link thumbnail to full size image for use with lightbox*/
    echo '<div style="background:url('.esc_url($featured_img_url).')">'; 
        the_title();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; 
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used is setting a CSS variable in the style for the `<div>`.

```
<div class="<?= has_post_thumbnail() ? 'has-background' : 'no-background'; ?>" style="--image: url( <?=get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?> );">
        <div class="text-block">
            <span>Company</span>
            <h1><?php the_field('page_title'); ?></h1>
            <p><?php the_field('intro_content'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.has-background {
   background-image: var(--image);
   /* other styles as needed */
}
```